# UITextField with black background, clearButton not visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I try to display a UITextfield with a black background.

But with this black background, the clearButton is not visible.
I can touch it... because I know where is supposed to be, but until
I touch it, nothing is visible.

Here's my code:

```
textField.background = [UIImage blackColor];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

How I can make the clearButton to appear ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi MBonevil., I have same issue! Can you please post your solution please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to draw and manage your own clear button, because there's no API for changing the appearance of the built-in button.  Read about the `rightView` and `rightViewMode` properties of [*UITextField*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).

Comment: I've created a subclass of UITextField. In this subclass, I used rightView to add and handle a custom delete button. This is the only solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use UIColor to set the background:

```
textField.background = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Last I checked, UITextField 'background' is a UIImage property, not UIColor.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a subclass of UITextField. In this subclass, I used rightView to add and handle a custom delete button. This is the only solution I've found.